# ViewModel like validation in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angular-ui-bootstrap, viewmodel

I'm having some difficulty envisioning a potential solution to a dilemma I'm facing, and I need some creative inspiration.

Essentially, I'm struggling to picture a good way to validate a form that can be thoughts of as having multiple nested forms. The challenge is that these nested forms are only rendered when a line item in the main form is clicked, causing a modal to open, at which time the rendering, model binding, etc. takes place, and the nested form can be validated.

The goal is to know whether or not there are validation errors down inside any of the main form's line items without having to open/render a modal for the item to find out. I'd also like to make sure that there's no duplication of validation logic, and that things are drawing from a single common set of validations rules that can be shared/accessed everywhere needed.

Ideally, I'd like to abstract out the validation logic such that it can be used by any ng-model bound element, but can also be used independent of rendering a form.

If anyone knows of any plug-ins that work well with AngularJs and sound well suited, please let me know.

**Clarification**

Though I'm open to checking out any plug-ins that might help, that's not really what I'm after. My main objective to is to find a way to validate my nested item data without opening/rendering the item's modal.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool or software library, or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers.

Answer (score 0):

I would use something that ensures that the user fills in these forms in a predefined format in the first place.
I use something called [inputmask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask) in my angularJs applications.
You can use a regex to define the format you want the inputs to be in.

You can also make sure that all the fields in the modal are in the right format before letting the user close the modal(This validation logic can come from a shared or common component).

Another option would be to make the modals hidden and not removed from the DOM so that the bindings remain even when the modal is no longer visible. You can add a red asterisk or something against the line which opens the modal to indicate errors in that modal's form.